# How to make Linux use the right driver (lshw)

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, drivers

I have an Edimax EW-7811Un wireless adapter which I am trying to get to work on my laptop which is running Debian 8.3.0 with LXDE. I have tried various things that I am going to describe below. But first I a want to say where I am stuck right now. Its that `lshw -C network` shows the wrong driver `rtl8192cu` which I blacklisted. Instead I installed the driver `8192cu` (without the rtl prefix).

`lsusb | grep -i edimax` shows the following

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
```

So, it uses a Realtek RTL8188CUS chip. A quick search in the Internet says that it uses the same driver as RTL8192CU.

I installed rtl8192cu-fixes driver according to [these instructions](http://textuploader.com/52ius). The instructions say that I am supposed to blacklist the `rtl8192cu` and `rtlwifi` modules that come with the Linux kernel, so I did so.

The new driver `8192cu` loads fine, the `lsmod | grep -i 8192cu` output is:

```
8192cu                520192  0 
usbcore               233472  10 uas,btusb,uvcvideo,usb_storage,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,usbhid,8192cu,xhci_hcd,xhci_pci
```

I enabled the adapter or driver (I am not quite sure which) with `sudo ifconfig wlan1 up`, because `sudo lshw -C network` was listing it as `DISABLED`.

Because there was a soft block when writing `sudo rfkill list all` I typed `sudo rfkill unblock all`.

Now the only thing that is left is letting Linux know that the right driver for my wireless adapter is `8192cu` and not `rtl8192cu`...

The current `sudo lshw -C network` output is (the relevant part):

```
  *-usb:0                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
       vendor: Realtek
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: wlan1
       version: 2.00
       serial: 00e04c000001
       capabilities: usb-2.00 ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu maxpower=500mA multicast=yes speed=480Mbit/s wireless=unassociated
```

Please note especially the last line where it says `driver=rtl8192cu`... :(

PS: Oh, yeah I forgot to mention that I did a Linux kernel upgrade, because that worked with another driver problem I had (backlight for a very new Intel CPU). But there weren't any results this time... :(

Edit: When I don't blacklist the Linux kernel modules `rtl8192cu` and `rtlwifi` the LED of the wireless adapter is always on, but the network manager WICD does not find any routers.

Edit2: On another laptop with the same OS and desktop (Debian + LXDE) it didn't work, either. But I also had Lubuntu 15.10 installed there, and the wireless adapter works with it. Lubuntu uses the `rtl8192cu` driver that comes with the kernel.

Comment: You might make some progress using the `bind` functionality in sysfs, as seen [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/575882/binding-device-to-a-driver-module), or `new_id` as in `echo 7392 7811 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/8192cu/new_id`

Answer (score 1):

I followed the link that Wumpus Q. Wumbley provided in his [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266176/how-to-make-linux-use-the-right-driver-lshw?noredirect=1#comment-460772), and after reading the question and some additional articles I found out that my driver was correctly recognized as it should be, but the developers of the driver `8192cu` decided to let the system think that the `rtl8192cu` driver is being used by keeping the folder structure and just symlinking to the new driver `8192cu`.

I then tried it with command line tools to scan for wireless routers as described in the article [Wi-Fi on the command line](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/wi-fi-command-line) and to my surprise my adapter found them alright.

Then I checked again with my Wicd Network Manager program, and found out that in the settings only `wlan0` (my PCI network card) was used, so I switched to `wlan1`, and Internet works now.

Initially the wireless speed was like 80KB/s in local network. It was plugged at a USB 3 port. I plugged it to a USB2 port, and the speeds are about 1-2MB/s. Still quite slow, but at least functional.